# Modify Css of Microsoft Qna Maker

Tags: css, azure, bots, botframework, azure-qna-maker

So I have QnA maker set up and connected to our Azure (I am totally new to Azure). I need to change the CSS of the Iframe from QNA maker, it is currently blue (as the default). I am following this guide to make it our company's colors:

https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/

I need to be able to clone this: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/src (which I already forked) into the current Azure build, which I am ultimately having a problem with.

I am sure I am overlooking something simple in Azure, but I just need to clone the source code to properly add the .css files I need to be able to edit the bot.

Currently, I have tried to grab the Iframe and change the CSS that way, but no dice (of course). All I need to do is change blue, to red, **any** way to do that will be helpful, whether that is changing the Iframe after it loads or by getting this guide to work for us. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to use [Git version control](https://git-scm.com/)?

Comment: No, but I will find out! Thank you, I saw a screenshot of this on one of my many guides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the github readme for more detail: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

There are options:

- Easiest: In any website, IFRAME the standard Web Chat channel
- **Easy**: In your non-React website, run Web Chat inline
- **Easyish**: In any website, IFRAME your Web Chat instance
- Medium: In your React website, incorporate the Web Chat React
  component

According to your requirements; running the bot in an iframe with custom style, you should read the *Easyish* section:

> You can isolate your instance of Web Chat by running it inside an
>   IFRAME. This involves creating two web pages:
>
> 1. Your Web Chat instance, **as shown above**. (refer to *Easy*)
> 2. The hosting page, adding `<iframe src="/path/to/your/webchat/instance" height="height" width="width" />`

Based on the *Easyish* section (step 1), you need to first complete the *Easy* section. In your existing web app, add a new page with the following code (enable directline on Azure Bot settings):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CUSTOMIZE** your chat box style by editing the botchat.css file. You make a copy from `https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css` and edit to your liking and put your own customized botchat.css to somewhere in your web app and change the href in the header instead of using the default one.

Finally for *Easyish* section step 2, you can create an iframe (content is step 1 web chat page) and embed that in your hosting page.

Comment: Thank you for the help! am running into a problem.
I have this current set up: 

 `<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
   <script>
     BotChat.App({
       directLine: { secret: '.7tU.qia_C-Yuey23FG-wAJwQ7SBI' },
       user: { id: 'userid' },
       bot: { id: 'botid' },
       resize: 'detect'
     }, document.getElementById("bot"));
   </script>
 </body>
`
Is there something I am missing and need to find the User id? I get a "couldn't send" everytime I ask a question to it.

Comment: yes you need to change the 'userid' and the 'botid' to your own. You can find this in your Azure Portal > Bot > Application Settings [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-manage-overview)

Comment: please mark this as an answer if you feel this helps you

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply, this is totally what we needed. We have been able to pull off everything else. Thank you!